# Finding rows by multiple columns

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am iterating over a large pandas table and want to do something if I find a row which matches several columns in another table. There are more columns in both tables which are not needed for the comparison. For example, output-table has like columns A, B, C, D and E and blacklist-table has A, B, C, D, E and F. I want to do something whenever a row in output-table matches blacklist-table in columns A and B. After reading through various topics about numpy and pandas, I got this far, but now I am stuck:

```
elif outputframe[((outputframe.A.isin(blacklist.A)) & (outputframe.B.isin(blacklist.B))).all()]:
    # Do something
```

It just says key-error: True. I want a true/false to be the result so I can use it in the if-condition.

I also tried something like this (which compiles and executes), but it doesn't find anything while there must be over thousand matches:

```
elif (currentrow['A'] in blacklist.A) & (currentrow['B'] in blacklist.B):
    # Do something
```

All values are strings of type unicode.

Comment: remove the `.all()` `outputframe[((outputframe.A.isin(blacklist.A)) & (outputframe.B.isin(blacklist.B)))]:`

Comment: @EdChum after removing the .all() it says: `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` Which lead me to include it in the first place.